# Send JSON data to ASP.NET HTTP Handler

Tags: asp.net, json, http, httphandler

i have an ASP.NET 4.0 HTTP handler that should receive and send data in json format. I'm using jquery to send json objects serialized in a string to the handler. It correctly sends the request but i don't know how i could retrieve the data from the httpcontext passed to the handler and how i could deserialize it... Can someone help me?

**UPDATE 1**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myurl.ashx",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: $.toJSON({
        ...
    }),
    success: function (response) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know the toJSON plugin, but what i know is that data expects a key/value pair object where the key is what you'll request from the Forms collection. So i guess the question is know, what your $.ToSJON call returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you send the data from jquery as a POST or GET request? In your Http Handler you can retrieve the values through the `HttpContext.Request` either via `Forms` or `QueryString`

ie. `string json = HttpContext.Current.Request.Forms["json"];`

To deserialize you can use the built in `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` class like this

```
string json = HttpContext.Current.Request.Forms["json"];
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
YourType obj = js.Deserialize<YourType>(json);
```

Comment: I'm sending the data as a POST request... if it can help, i'm trying to make a really simple comet c# server implemented over the bayeux protocol. I don't know if in this case it's better to send the data as a GET request but anyway in the Request.Form collection there are 0 items

Comment: If you're sending as POST the Forms-collection should not be null. How does your jquery-code look like?

Comment: this is a very old post, but I thought I'd point to a good answer --the forms collection should be empty, and you need to parse the request input stream; the answer is most likely here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421351/post-json-object-array-to-ihttphandler