# POST json object array to IHttpHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, ihttphandler

Im constructing an array of objects like this:

```
var postData = [];

$.each(selectedFields, function (index, value) {
    var testTitle = 'testing ' + index;
    postData.push({title: testTitle, title2 : testTitle});        
}
```

I then post it like this(note that i have tried a number of different aproaches):

```
$.post('SaveTitlesHandler.ashx', { form : postData }, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I then try to get the data in a handler...

```
public class SaveTitlesHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string json = context.Request.Form.ToString();
    }

}
```

I cant seem to get proper json out of the request. Anyone got any idea?

cheers.

twD

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not posting JSON. You are using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So inside the handler you could access individual values:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var title1 = context.Request["form[0][title]"];
    var title2 = context.Request["form[0][title2]"];

    var title3 = context.Request["form[1][title]"];
    var title4 = context.Request["form[1][title2]"];

    ...
}
```

If you wanted to POST real JSON you need this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'SaveTitlesHandler.ashx',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

and then inside the handler read from the request input stream:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
    {
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

The `JSON.stringify` method converts a javascript object into a JSON string and it is a native method built-in modern browsers. You might also need to include [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) if you want to support older browsers.

Comment: Do you know of a simple way to post the data as JSON?

Comment: When i try that the Request.Form is just an empty string?
Am i missing something?

Comment: @twDuke, in the first example yuo should not use `Request.Form[...]` as shown in my answer. You should use `Request[...]` directly

Comment: Yes, i saw that :) The thing was i tried the $.ajax thing and didnt see the updated code for the handler, so form was obiously empty. 
But works now that i use the stream!